# How does DNS caching work for websites behind CDN?

Tags: dns, cdn, dns-cache

Many websites use DNS servers from CDNs like Cloudflare that hide their origin IP with reverse proxy. how do the DNS caching servers work in these situations? because many websites can show to be using the same IP address, Cloudflare's, so I assume that'd result in many errors for clients/users of DNS caching services, like the one in Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When it comes to Cloudflare which is both CDN and authoritative DNS server, how do the DNS caching services like the one built in Windows or other caching server software, know which IP address belongs to which domain?

They **don't need** to know that. All DNS caches, just as DNS itself, only map domain names *to* values ('A' records) – never the other way around.

> If for example the DNS caching software remembers that 1.2.3.4 points to facebook.com and also that IP is for google.com, bing.com etc., the cache is useless, so what am I missing?

No, that's not what DNS caching software remembers at all. It does the opposite – both the DNS cache, and the DNS system as a whole, only care that `google.com` points to `1.2.3.4`, not that the address "points" back.

Entries in the DNS cache look exactly like entries in authoritative DNS servers, with domain name as the lookup key. (In fact, beyond Windows, most DNS caches *are* just ordinary DNS servers that take standard queries and answer them.)

---

It is also not anything new to have multiple DNS entries resolving to the same address. (For example, even without a CDN, everyone has been using HTTP "virtual hosting" to host tens or hundreds of different websites on the same servers – accordingly with hundreds of DNS names resolving to the same server addresses.)

---

> so DNS caching services cache the end result of a DNS query, which is the origin server IP address

Yes in general, however, when you're using a CDN such as Cloudflare, the end result of that DNS query *is not* the origin server anymore – it is the CDN server.

With Cloudflare in particular, the table of DNS records that you're seeing in Cloudflare's "control panel" is not actually the DNS records that Cloudflare serves to users. As soon as you enable proxying for a domain name, Cloudflare's authoritative DNS servers will instead start replying with *the CDN's own* IP addresses instead of the ones you've entered.

(Other CDNs work the same way, as the entire point of using a CDN is that your clients talk to it. For example, the `superuser.com` domain uses the Fastly CDN so it always resolves to IP addresses of nearby Fastly nodes.)

The purpose of short TTLs with CDNs is therefore not protection, but load-balancing (the CDN's authoritative server dynamically responds with "best" nodes at the moment, both in terms of load and geolocation).

> When multiple DNS entries resolve to the same IP address, like google.com and facebook.com both resolve to 1.2.3.4, which element/component in the network is responsible to take the user to the correct website?

It's actually the client and the server, not the network.

Every HTTP client specifies the requested domain as part of the HTTP request – that's the "Host" header in HTTP/1.1 (or the ":authority" pseudo-header in HTTP/2). Web servers or reverse-proxies will map the received Host value to the corresponding <VirtualHost> or similar configuration.

*(You can see all request headers using the <kbd>F12</kbd> "Developer tools" in a browser – open the "Network" tab to start collecting data, then go back to the browser and hit F5 to reload the webpage, and go back to the "Network" section.)*

Similarly, TLS clients also specify the requested domain as the "Server Name Indication" extension in TLS ClientHello so that the server could send the correct certificate.

In general each protocol has its own way of doing this, and not all protocols actually distinguish different domain names at all. (For example, SSH doesn't provide such information to the server as the goal isn't to connect to a "domain" but to the machine itself.)

But the *network* (at IP layer) doesn't care about domains (or websites) at all – its only job is to deliver packets to 1.2.3.4, and if the IP address is the same, then the destination server is also the same. ("Destination server" being the CDN reverse-proxy frontend, in this case.)

Comment: When multiple DNS entries resolve to the same IP address, like google.com and facebook.com both resolve to 1.2.3.4, which element/component in the network is responsible to take the user to the correct website? like when person A and person B both live in the same house, how does someone send them a letter that only goes to person B.

Comment: @elias: Clients specify the desired domain name as part of every HTTP request (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

A company that uses a CDN will set up duplicate servers around the world.
These servers are known to all the CDN servers.

The one and same IP address you mentioned points to one DNS server
which is part of the CDN.

This DNS server will only forward the DNS request to a further DNS server
that will be the authoritative server for the domain.
It may not give the final answer itself (it's not required to),
so this will behave as the usual DNS hierarchy of servers.
The choice of this authoritative server is mostly influenced by the
geographical location of the client's IP.

The final answer for the DNS query will be a company web server that is
serving the queried domain (belongs to the queried domain),
which is judged to be the "nearest".

To avoid problems and congestion, the DNS response will have a small
time-to-live (TTL), so the process may repeat itself from time to time,
and perhaps return another server the next time.

Comment: When it comes to Cloudflare which is both CDN and authoritative DNS server, how do the DNS caching services like the one built in Windows or other caching server software, know which IP address belongs to which domain?
the same Cloudflare IP can be shown as the IP address of hundreds of websites when doing a whois lookup. if for example the DNS caching software remembers that 1.2.3.4 points to facebook.com and also that IP is for google.com, bing.com etc., the cache is useless, so what am I missing?

Comment: They cache the IP address of the company server which is the end result of the DNS search. They will also cache the DNS server that identified itself as authoritative server for the domain (although with a short TTL). The CDN uses the standard DNS protocol, the new idea being the fact of pointing to a CDN server that is nearby, rather than to a DNS server in the global hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know, so DNS caching services cache the end result of a DNS query, which is the origin server IP address. I think that gives away the IP address of the websites that are behind Cloudflare and want to be protected against DDoS?

Comment: No, the short TTL protects against it, as the CDN server also does load-balancing. The only effect of a DDOS attack will be the choosing of a new company server after the TTL.

Comment: So for a short time, even few seconds, a bad actor trying to find the origin IP of a website, can just set up a caching server and visit website behind Cloudflare in the browser, then view cached entries and determine the origin server's IP address?
and sorry about that.

Comment: What is a bad about making a DNS query and caching the IP?

Comment: Website owners, I think, use Cloudflare to hide their webserver's IP address so they don't get DDoSed and instead let the requests go through Cloudflare network and any DDoS be mitigated by them, and if like you said, the caching server can look past Cloudflare and view the webserver's actual IP address, then bad actor can use it to DDoS the webserver directly and Cloudflare won't be able to mitigate it.

Comment: You're still misunderstanding the concept : Website owners use Cloudflare for two purposes: 1. Best user response time by using a near server, 2. Load-balancing in case of the nearest server being overloaded (DDOS and more) and then pointing to the next-nearest.